# Incoherence between execution in cmd and batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

During the execution of a command in the cmd my written application runs fine :

```
C:\Users\BTO-user>C:\Python33\python.exe C:\cygwin\bin\TIP\srcpython\TIP.py
```

But when I doubleclick the python an error popups "python.exe has stopped working"
When I try to bypass this via a .bat file for automatic launching, the same error occurs.

```
@echo off
C:\Python33\python.exe "C:\cygwin\bin\TIP\srcpython\TIP.py"
exit
```

So I my opinion the python interpreter should be different for both cases, so I verified the command assoc and ftype to see the what the doubleclick exactly does.

```
C:\Users\BTO-user>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\Users\BTO-user>ftype Python.file
Python.file="C:\Python33\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

But as you can see the execution path is the same. Why is there a difference in execution between first and second execution methods? The first one is succesful the second fails.

Comment: The second one has `"` around `C:\cygwin\bin\TIP\srcpython\TIP.py`. The first one doesn't.

Comment: Also, the first one has C:\Users\BTO-user as current directory; the second one may be not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of PA is correct.His correction makes it work. Althought I'm not sure why works as my commands and my argument are indicated by their full path reference. I don't see why I need to be in that repository before it works.